# Isn't the Array object different from the Object (thought typeof on both returns the same value)?

Tags: javascript, arrays, prototype

two of these tests fail.  can anyone explain why and how to fix it?

```js
var assert = require('assert').strict

Number.prototype.isNbr = true
Number.prototype.isStr = false
Number.prototype.isObj = false
Number.prototype.isArr = false

String.prototype.isNbr = false
String.prototype.isStr = true
String.prototype.isObj = false
String.prototype.isArr = false

Array.prototype.isNbr = false
Array.prototype.isStr = false
Array.prototype.isObj = false
Array.prototype.isArr = true

Object.prototype.isNbr = false
Object.prototype.isStr = false
Object.prototype.isObj = true
Object.prototype.isArr = false

describe('Number', () => {
    var x = 0;
    it('Is number', () => { assert.ok(x.isNbr) })
    it('Is string', () => { assert.ok(!x.isStr) })
    it('Is object', () => { assert.ok(!x.isObj) })
    it('Is array', () => { assert.ok(!x.isObj) })
})

describe('String', () => {
    var x = ''; 
    it('Is number', () => { assert.ok(!x.isNbr) })
    it('Is string', () => { assert.ok(x.isStr) })
    it('Is object', () => { assert.ok(!x.isObj) })
    it('Is array', () => { assert.ok(!x.isObj) })
})

describe('Object', () => {
    var x = {}; 
    it('Is number', () => { assert.ok(!x.isNbr) })
    it('Is string', () => { assert.ok(!x.isStr) })
    it('Is object', () => { assert.ok(x.isObj) })
    it('Is array', () => { assert.ok(!x.isObj) })
})

describe('Array', () => {
    var x = []; 
    it('Is number', () => { assert.ok(!x.isNbr) })
    it('Is string', () => { assert.ok(!x.isStr) })
    it('Is object', () => { assert.ok(!x.isObj) })
    it('Is array', () => { assert.ok(x.isObj) })
})
```

You can save to a file `t.js` and run like this:

```sh
$ mocha t.js
```

**edit I**

corrected line

```js
var x = [];
```

which @MarkMeyer pointed out was wrong.  in my original it was correct and correcting it doesn't change the results

Comment: This is confusing: why are you defining `var x = {};` in your array test? And why are you testing for `is array` with `it('Is array', () => { assert.ok(x.isObj) })` `isObj` ? You never actually use `isArr` in the tests.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. An array _is_ an object. All these boxed types _are_ objects.

Comment: JavaScript is an object-oriented language. Almost everything is an object. Consider this: `typeof null` `typeof new String()` `typeof new Number()` `typeof new Map()` and so on.

Comment: `null` is admittedly a weird one with `typeof`. It's `"object"`, but it isn't actually derived from `Object.prototype`.

Comment: Monkeying with prototypes of base types is [strongly discouraged](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/The_performance_hazards_of__%5B%5BPrototype%5D%5D_mutation). Why do you want to do this? What are you solving here?

Comment: In addition the testing is flawed. An array will look on the Array.prototype and find `isObj` is false, which is wrong. This prevents it from looking on the Object prototype. It would be better to test with `instanceof Object`

Comment: @MarkMeyer, my bad.  I've fixed the code but the issue stands

Comment: @PatrickRoberts: Array and Object are separate objects

Comment: @spender, I just want to understand why this is weird

Comment: You are using `isObj` everywhere instead of using `isArr` for the last test in every section

Comment: @Lends that's because you're instantiating an object.  if you do `var s = ''; typeof s` you'll get 'string', not 'object'

Comment: @Paulpro, gosh.  my bad as well.  let me fix that

Comment: @Paulpro.  gosh.  I have egg on my face now :(

Comment: @ekkis Array is a superset of Object. Note `new Array() instanceof Object`, `Array.prototype instanceof Object`, and `Object.getPrototypeOf(Array.prototype) === Object.prototype`. They are separate objects, sure, but an Array _is_ an instance of Object.

Comment: @ekkis yep, it's like `typeof` of function is a `function` but a function is still an object. And those numbers and strings still have properties and methods which make them objects. JavaScript is object-oriented af.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as @Paulpro cleverly pointed out, my tests are bad.  I was checking for `.isObj` where I should have been checking for `.isArr`

if I fix that everything works

Answer (score 0):

To test for an array use `Array.isArray(val)`:

```js
var a = [1,2,3];
var b = {a:1};

console.log(Array.isArray(a));
console.log(Array.isArray(b));
```

The biggest reason your code was failing was because you were not calling `.isArr`. Look back at your code. You are calling `.isObj` twice in each.

```js
var assert = {
  ok(val) {
    if (!val) {
      console.error(`The value ${val} was not true.`);
    }
    else {
      console.info('     ✓');
    }
  }
}

function describe(text, fn) {
  console.log(`Running test for: ${text}`);
  fn();
}

function it(text, fn) {
  console.log(`  -- ${text}`);
  fn();
}

Number.prototype.isNbr = true
Number.prototype.isStr = false
Number.prototype.isObj = false
Number.prototype.isArr = false

String.prototype.isNbr = false
String.prototype.isStr = true
String.prototype.isObj = false
String.prototype.isArr = false

Array.prototype.isNbr = false
Array.prototype.isStr = false
Array.prototype.isObj = false
Array.prototype.isArr = true

Object.prototype.isNbr = false
Object.prototype.isStr = false
Object.prototype.isObj = true
Object.prototype.isArr = false

describe('Number', () => {
    var x = 0;
    it('Is number', () => { assert.ok(x.isNbr) })
    it('Is string', () => { assert.ok(!x.isStr) })
    it('Is object', () => { assert.ok(!x.isObj) })
    it('Is array', () => { assert.ok(!x.isArr) })
})

describe('String', () => {
    var x = ''; 
    it('Is number', () => { assert.ok(!x.isNbr) })
    it('Is string', () => { assert.ok(x.isStr) })
    it('Is object', () => { assert.ok(!x.isObj) })
    it('Is array', () => { assert.ok(!x.isArr) })
})

describe('Object', () => {
    var x = {}; 
    it('Is number', () => { assert.ok(!x.isNbr) })
    it('Is string', () => { assert.ok(!x.isStr) })
    it('Is object', () => { assert.ok(x.isObj) })
    it('Is array', () => { assert.ok(!x.isArr) })
})

describe('Array', () => {
    var x = []; 
    it('Is number', () => { assert.ok(!x.isNbr) })
    it('Is string', () => { assert.ok(!x.isStr) })
    it('Is object', () => { assert.ok(!x.isObj) })
    it('Is array', () => { assert.ok(x.isArr) })
})
```

But this is not the best way to test these types. You are changing the `prototype` of built in objects. That is generally considered a bad practice.

You could do this:

```js
var assert = {
  ok(val) {
    if (!val) {
      console.error(`The value ${val} was not true.`);
    }
    else {
      console.info('     ✓');
    }
  }
}

function describe(text, fn) {
  console.log(`Running test for: ${text}`);
  fn();
}

function it(text, fn) {
  console.log(`  -- ${text}`);
  fn();
}

const isNbr = val => Object.prototype.toString.apply(val).slice(8,-1) === 'Number'
const isStr = val => Object.prototype.toString.apply(val).slice(8,-1) === 'String';
const isFun = val => Object.prototype.toString.apply(val).slice(8,-1) === 'Function';
const isObj = val => Object.prototype.toString.apply(val).slice(8,-1) === 'Object';
const isArr = val => Array.isArray(val);

describe('Number', () => {
    var x = 0;
    it('Is number', () => { assert.ok(isNbr(x)) })
    it('Is string', () => { assert.ok(!isStr(x)) })
    it('Is object', () => { assert.ok(!isObj(x)) })
    it('Is function', () => { assert.ok(!isFun(x)) })
    it('Is array', () => { assert.ok(!isArr(x)) })
})

describe('Function', () => {
    var x = () => {};
    it('Is number', () => { assert.ok(!isNbr(x)) })
    it('Is string', () => { assert.ok(!isStr(x)) })
    it('Is object', () => { assert.ok(!isObj(x)) })
    it('Is function', () => { assert.ok(isFun(x)) })
    it('Is array', () => { assert.ok(!isArr(x)) })
})

describe('String', () => {
    var x = ''; 
    it('Is number', () => { assert.ok(!isNbr(x)) })
    it('Is string', () => { assert.ok(isStr(x)) })
    it('Is object', () => { assert.ok(!isObj(x)) })
    it('Is function', () => { assert.ok(!isFun(x)) })
    it('Is array', () => { assert.ok(!isArr(x)) })
})

describe('Object', () => {
    var x = {}; 
    it('Is number', () => { assert.ok(!isNbr(x)) })
    it('Is string', () => { assert.ok(!isStr(x)) })
    it('Is object', () => { assert.ok(isObj(x)) })
    it('Is function', () => { assert.ok(!isFun(x)) })
    it('Is array', () => { assert.ok(!isArr(x)) })
})

describe('Array', () => {
    var x = []; 
    it('Is number', () => { assert.ok(!isNbr(x)) })
    it('Is string', () => { assert.ok(!isStr(x)) })
    it('Is object', () => { assert.ok(!isObj(x)) })
    it('Is function', () => { assert.ok(!isFun(x)) })
    it('Is array', () => { assert.ok(isArr(x)) })
})

describe('Null', () => {
    var x = null; 
    it('Is number', () => { assert.ok(!isNbr(x)) })
    it('Is string', () => { assert.ok(!isStr(x)) })
    it('Is object', () => { assert.ok(!isObj(x)) })
    it('Is function', () => { assert.ok(!isFun(x)) })
    it('Is array', () => { assert.ok(!isArr(x)) })
})
```

Comment: I added both the reason and a better way to write your tests so you are not adding the the `prototype` of built in objects.

Comment: thanks but I'm building a library of prototypes methods so your approach is not suitable for my purposes

Comment: also, aside from possible collisions between libraries I don't see why it would be a bad practice.  the current objects already provide a bunch of functionality but it's missing so it's only natural to want to complement it